# How can I skip n lines of a binary stdin using Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, optimization, binaryfiles

I'm piping binary data to a Python script on a Hadoop cluster using the Hadoop CLI. The binary data have terminators that identify where new documents begin. The records are sorted by a unique identifier which starts at 1000000001 and increments by 1.

I am trying to save the data only for a subset of these IDs which I have in a dictionary.

My current process is to select the data from the CLI using:

```
hadoop select "Database" "Collection" | cut -d$'\t' -f2 | python script.py
```

and process it in script.py which looks like this:

```
import json
import sys

member_mapping = json.load(open('member_mapping.json'))

output = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    person = json.loads(line)
    if member_mapping.get(person['personId']):
        output.append({person['personId']: person})
    if len(output) == len(member_mapping):
        break
```

The problem is that there are 6.5M IDs in this binary data and it takes almost 2 hours to scan. I know the min() and max() IDs in my dictionary and you can see in my code that I stop early when I have saved n documents where n is the length of my mapping file.

I want to make this process more efficient by skipping as many reads as possible. If the ID starts at 1000000001 and the first ID I want to save is 1000010001, can I simply *skip* 10,000 lines?

Due to system issues, I'm not currently able to use spark or any other tools that may improve this process, so I need to stick to solutions that utilize Python and the Hadoop CLI for now.

Comment: `sys.stdin` acts like a buffer and should support the `read` function. You might be able to just say `lines = sys.stdin.read(10000); while lines:`. I'm not going to guarantee that though

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `enumerate` and a threshold, and then skip any input that isn't in the rane you care about. This isn't a direct fix, but should run much faster and throw those first 10,000 lines away pretty quick.

```
for lineNum, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if(lineNum < 10000):
         continue
    person = json.loads(line)
    if member_mapping.get(person['personId']):
        output.append({person['personId']: person})
    if len(output) == len(member_mapping):
        break
```